# Can't make jQuery UI dialog work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, requirejs

I try to use jQuery UI library. I made it AMD using [this](https://github.com/jrburke/jqueryui-amd) plugin, and have a simple code of:

```
<div class="#dialog" title="Test">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

That I try to show in dialog inside backbone's render function like this:

```
render:function ()
        this.$el.html(companyTemplate);
        ...
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        return this;
    },
```

there are no errors in the console, and nothing happens. I did reqire it in *define()* and include the appropriate css in my main page.

**UPD** autocomplete works fine, seems like it's related to dialog.

Comment: I think you will need to explain AMD.

Comment: Have you ensured the Render is being called? Try putting an alert('Hello'); and see if that comes up.

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't see anything in my view. I tried to debug it, and finished somewhere in widget-bridge

Comment: How exactly can I explain AMD? This script simply turns all widgets into AMD files that I can import with require.js without polluting the global namespace, asynchronously loaded and only the widgets that I need in the current scope.

Comment: If I know "how", I wouldn't need to ask for an explanation. You could at least say what the acronym stands for.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought require.js tag means it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div id="dialog" title="Test">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="dialog" title="Test">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>

$(".dialog").dialog();
```

Comment: With explanation... #dialog in the jQuery selector refers to an element with the ID of dialog. Not a class of #dialog. Class and ID names must begin with an alpha character I believe